# How to have GitHub Actions run asp.net core unit test during the CI/CD process. The test source file "projectname.dll" provided was not found

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions

Hello I am running into an issue when trying to run unit test that are part of my asp.net core solution, but housed in a separate project. I tried adding dotnet test stuff into my build step of my workflow yaml file, but I am being presented with the error.

"The test source file "D:\a\NHASoftware\NHASoftware\NHA.Testing\bin\Debug\net6.0\NHA.Testing.dll" provided was not found."

The test source file "D:\a\NHASoftware\NHASoftware\NHASoftware\bin\Debug\net6.0\NHA.Website.Software.dll" provided was not found.

Here is a look into my project structure and workflow file. The code can be found here https://github.com/jlarnett/NHASoftware

[Software Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb7cT.png)

Here is the github action workflow yaml file.

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - NHAIndustries

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      #run the unit test
      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
        
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'NHAIndustries'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_FCD9B13EA7C1429AB2F6866C10252682 }}
          package: .
```

I appreciate any help, I am a self taught software developer and trying to learn CI/CD, but the documentation isn't exactly the most helpful I have found.

I have tried adding the unit test section that is seen in the workflow yaml file above.

Comment: I think it could be because you didn't specify the configuration to the test command. See how the path it mentions says "Debug" (which is default configuration)? You specified "--configuration Release" to build, so try specifying it to test as well.

Comment: make sure that correct paths to test DLLs are provided to .net test command  ensure that you are specifying correct paths for both test projects and referenced project

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the quick replies and help. The problem was changing the build configuration to release as Hasan Raza mentioned. I spent wayyyy to long looking at this issue before asking a question. Juunas I appreciate your answer also, and will keep the idea of adding a path to DLLs if other issues arise.